# How to check confirm password with zod

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, validation, zod

How do I check for confirm password with zod?. I want to validate for confirm password with Zod. I want Zod to compare my password with comparePassword

```
export const registerUSerSchema = z.object({
    firstName: z.string(),
    lastName: z.string(),
    userName: z.string(),
    email: z.string().email(),
    phone: z.string().transform(data => Number(data)),
    password: z.string().min(4),
    confirmPassword: z.string().min(4),
    avatar: z.string().optional(),
    isVerified: z.boolean().optional()
})
```

Answer (score 51):

You can achieve this by tacking on a [`superRefine`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#superRefine)

```js
export const registerUserSchema = z.object({
    firstName: z.string(),
    lastName: z.string(),
    userName: z.string(),
    email: z.string().email(),
    phone: z.string().transform(data => Number(data)),
    password: z.string().min(4),
    confirmPassword: z.string().min(4),
    avatar: z.string().optional(),
    isVerified: z.boolean().optional()
}).superRefine(({ confirmPassword, password }, ctx) => {
  if (confirmPassword !== password) {
    ctx.addIssue({
      code: "custom",
      message: "The passwords did not match"
    });
  }
});
```

If the passwords fail to parse for the base reason (not at least 4 characters) then that error will come through, but if the whole base object succeeds to parse, then the super refine check will happen.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.
Since I was using MVC, I decided to us `if statement` implement it in my controller logic. Incase of next time, I will follow this approach.

`if (record.password != record.confirmPassword) {
  throw "Password and Confirm password didn't match";
 }`

Comment: make sure you add `path: ['confirmPassword']` to the object passed in to the `addIssue` method if you want the error tied to that field

Comment: Make sure to add `path` as it provides a key for you to display the error message
`ctx.addIssue({
          code: 'custom',
          message: 'passwords do not match',
          path: ['confirm'],
        });`

Answer (score 37):

I have like this:

```
const validationSchema = z
    .object({
        name: string().min(1, { message: "Name is required" }), // pass custom message
        email: string().email(),
        website: string().optional(),
        country: string(),
        password: string(),
        confirm: string(),
    })
    .refine((data) => data.password === data.confirm, {
        message: "Passwords don't match",
        path: ["confirm"],
    });
```

I am using React Hook Form.

Here are some docs, I copy and pasted for you, so you can see how it works: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jqTth88I-D0-qzq34B4sUGbp8wGmExS7kpc78QA_4sk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If user writes `cofirm` > `password` then `rhf` still shows error, no? ``

Answer (score 6):

You can implement `refine` function like this:

```
const passwordForm = z
  .object({
    password: z.string(),
    confirmPassword: z.string(),
  })
  .refine((data) => data.password === data.confirmPassword, {
    message: "Passwords don't match",
    path: ["confirmPassword"], // path of error
  });

passwordForm.parse({ password: "asdf", confirmPassword: "qwer" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   export const registerUserSchema = z.object({
    firstName: z.string(),
    lastName: z.string(),
    userName: z.string(),
    email: z.string().email(),
    phone: z.string().transform(data => Number(data)),
    password: z.string().min(4),
    confirmPassword: z.string().min(4),
    avatar: z.string().optional(),
    isVerified: z.boolean().optional()
}).refine(
      (values) => {
        return values.password === values.confirmPassword;
      },
      {
        message: "Passwords must match!",
        path: ["confirmPassword"],
      }
    );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).