# How to compare 2 different fields in a form? (React Hook Form + Zod)

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hook-form, zod

Let's say I need to validate this object:

```
{
  productionData: {
    manufacturing: {
      productionDate: "2010-01-01"
    },
  },
  salesData: {
    sellingDate: "2009-01-01"
  }
}
```

I want to compare the `sellingDate` against `productionDate` and display an error if the date is earlier. What is the best way to do this? This is a simplified example, I could have the 2 fields nested at very different levels inside the form object.

Is there a way I can access the whole form data from inside the validation schema and reference a specific property?

I know about `.refine()`, but this would work only if the properties are in the same object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check confirm password with zod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73695535/how-to-check-confirm-password-with-zod)

Comment: @Souperman - not really. that answer is only for the case where the 2 properties are nested in the same object, at the same level

Comment: on second thought, I just tested again and I can indeed use superRefine for a workaround